# SPRING MVC: How can I render ModelAndView into a string

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Inside Controller I need to get a rendered string and do some actions with it. This string has to be rendered out of a view. Is there a simple way of doing it?

Clarification:

I have controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@ResponseBody
public String renderString() {

//I NEED TO RENDER SOME CONTENT I SAVED IN A VIEW
//I DONT WANT TO RETURN THIS CONTENT BACK TO THE BROWSER
//INSTEAD I WANT TO LETS SAY SEND CONTENT VIA EMAIL

ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("email_template", Model);

**//QUESTION IS HERE, HOW DO I GET RENDERED STRING OUT OF VIEW/MODEL?
String emailText = view.render(); ??????????** 

...sendEmail(emailText);


return "Email send";
}
```

Hope is more clear now

Comment: Can you add some of your problem code so that everyone can understand your problem clearly. And please some more description about what you want to achieve very clearly.

Comment: we need more details to help you

Comment: I think what you need is a templating engine - see a related question here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/174204/204788

Comment: Yes looks like StringTemplate mentioned in that thread should do the job. I will give it a try. However I was hoping to do it with SPRING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Japs told you, I'm not sure to really understand your question, but I'll go for what I think "out of a view" means.

With Spring you can add the annotation @ResponseBody to your Controller. The String returned by the method will then be the only content of the response.

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@ResponseBody
public String renderString() {
    return "Rendered String";
}
```

You will get "Rendered String" at screen.